# sample Evaluation function

Tags: haskell

This is a simple code from my lecture notes. I dont understand it very well. Can anyone explain to me what is meaning of "case (eval e1, eval e2) of". From my understanding, this command should work for const Int. There is no line talk about eval e1->bool.

```
-- Simple expressions
--
data Expr = Const Int
          | Add   Expr Expr       -- arguments must be Ints
          | Equal Expr Expr       -- arguments must be of same type
          | If    Expr Expr Expr  -- 1st argument must be a Bool

-- Evaluation results
--
data Value = IntV  Int
           | BoolV Bool
           deriving Show

-- Evaluate a simple expression.
--
eval :: Expr -> Value
eval (Const i)     = IntV i
eval (Add e1 e2)   = 
  case (eval e1, eval e2) of
    (IntV i1, IntV i2) -> IntV $ i1 + i2
    _                  -> error "Add: Int expected"
eval (Equal e1 e2) =
  case (eval e1, eval e2) of
    (IntV  i1, IntV  i2) -> BoolV $ i1 == i2
    (BoolV b1, BoolV b2) -> BoolV $ b1 == b2
    _                    -> error "Equal: same types expected"
eval (If ec et ee) =
  case eval ec of
    BoolV flag
      | flag      -> eval et
      | otherwise -> eval ee
    _             -> error "If: conditional must be Bool"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` statement is a bit like a `switch` statement from other languages. The expression between the `case` and the `of` is matched against each pattern in order until one matches. The last case `_` matches everything, a bit like a `default` case in a Java switch statement.

e.g.

```
-- simple data type which just wraps a value
data Foo a = Foo a

n = Foo 1

describe :: Foo Int -> String
describe n = case n of
               Foo 0 -> "Zero"
               Foo 1 -> "One"
               Foo 2 -> "Two"
               _     -> "Every other Foo Int!"
```

The example from your code combines two expressions in a tuple so they can be pattern matched at the same time:

```
case (eval e1, eval e2) of
    (IntV i1, IntV i2) -> IntV $ i1 + i2
    _                  -> error "Add: Int expected"
```

It's convenient and shorter than matching both individually, which might look something like this:

```
case eval e1 of
    IntV i1 -> case eval e2 of
                   IntV i2 -> IntV $ i1 + i2
                   _       -> error "Add: Int expected"
    _       -> error "Add: Int expected"
```

Comment: actually, I very confused with the "(eval e1,eval e2)". Does it mean eval take e1 as a argument run the eval again? That is make sense if e1 = Const i. But I dont understand what happen when e1 = bool

Comment: Yes, it will call `eval` again on the sub-expressions.

Comment: ok, for example. e1 = 5, it call itself again and pattern match the eval (Const i)     = IntV i and get 5. What happened if e1 is a boolean? there is no patter match for it.

Comment: e1 cannot be 5. It could be `Const 5`, in which case it will be evaluated by the first definition of eval, `eval (Const i) = IntV i`, which produces `IntV 5`.

Comment: but how can we get (BoolV b1, BoolV b2) from (eval e1, eval e2). It doesn't like (IntV i1, IntV i2) which can be get from (Const i) = IntV i

Comment: `BoolV` values can only be created by calling `eval` on an `Equal` expression. Consider an expression like: "if 1 = 2 then 5 else 6" which, in your language, is: `e1 = If (Equal (Const 1) (Const 2)) (Const 5) (Const 6)`. When you say `eval e1` it will match the "If" definition of eval, which first evaluates the condition, by calling `eval (Equal (Const 1) (Const 2))`. This will match the "Equal" definition for eval, which in turn evaluates `Const 1` and `Const 2`, and eventually returns `BoolV False`

Comment: To answer your specific question from the last comment, to get `(BoolV b1, BoolV b2)` from `(eval e1, eval e2)`, both `e1` and `e2` must be expressions of the form `Equal e3 e4`.